# How to check if user has liked product or not sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, foreign-keys, relation

I have three tables User , subproducts and Likes

```
db.SubProduct.hasMany(db.Like, { foreignKey: "ProductId", as: "likes" });
db.Users.hasMany(db.Like, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "likedProducts" });
db.Like.belongsTo(db.Users,{foreignKey: "userId", as: "likedProducts"})
db.Like.belongsTo(db.SubProduct, { foreignKey: "ProductId", as: "likes" });
```

this is my foreign keys to link tables to each other

I am calling this function to fetch the subproducts with likeCount field in it

```
const Products = await db.SubProduct.findAll({
  attributes: { 
    include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("likes.id")), "LikeCount"]] 
},
  include: [
    {
      model: db.Like, as: "likes", attributes: []
    }
  ],
  group: ['SubProduct.id']
});
```

the function is working fine it is giving me the product data with likecount in it.

but I want get one field along with a field `isLiked` which will `true or false` .
if the user id which is provided in the token has liked that product then the isLiked field will be `true` otherwise it will be `false`

here is the reference question from where I got this function to get likecount now I want to learn about how  to get isLiked field

[How can users like and unlike each others post using sequelize postgres nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64859383/14936090)